# Small Footprint Linux for VM

Tags: distributions

I apologize if this is already answered somewhere. But here is the issue.

I am running Arch as my host. I want to run a small footprint VM on this machine, which I can do the following with :

1. Should run in seamless mode (although I installed vbox extension
   pack from AUR, i cant get it working)
2. Should work with any kind of wifi out of the box (I plan to make an ova
   and share the machine)
3. Should be able to access the package repo of modern linuxes, e.g. AUR or
   Apt-Get repos
4. Should run a very small GUI
5. Should have a very small ISO size.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't know about the GUI stuff, but there are some tiny distros available as container images with Docker. You might be able to put something together.

Comment: Try Alpine Linux. I use it whenever I need a small footprint VM.